# Angular webpush sendNotification blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular

When I try to send a pwa notification on Angular with the sendNotification method of [web-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push), I get the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://wns2-db5p.notify.windows.com/w/?token=BQYAAACrA0Lgie%2bFSZFyBN0VhXRiFJoCVdAvO19FGHDBPfDGascLuRGTCNhEs57P7BGoNWVFEVay9f0JOGY3HzyMAPrpf94WbH5PM6BI1hrCTFe7DLMQaJtGtlyjvgsF0QFFO30WDtinoo4cKjWyCJcvCS%2bJZjz014dvOy42deKefFklEp3jLq29DIINLCKo1DIxlQRmfljCEoRmtMXuLShaIHVG9AM1b4ZKKkXIUxx%2bzSW38UrWtgZoQkPpKM3rMRQNpQkkahXDsOruXYn8sJMLSF0kfaBvs%2by36HBSL%2fsM8K52w6fIcTA4C3%2f2ephKGSCXQrJNcUxf2sAkDDR2ghNwv8F6' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I access my site with the following link: http://127.0.0.1:8080/

Below is my code, the error happens after **webpush.sendNotification**:

```
const VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY = "BML9Py6LHPBuJqFT0vKB4jk5NCv-Jfl1O__97PkVanHqJa5uzFD-TlUzgY-enxXQCirAbMVGQJQ-gdXaFlQUtGM";
this.swPush.requestSubscription({
    serverPublicKey: VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY
})
.then(sub => {
    this.sub = sub;
    this.sub.keys = {
      "p256dh": "BML9Py6LHPBuJqFT0vKB4jk5NCv-Jfl1O__97PkVanHqJa5uzFD-TlUzgY-enxXQCirAbMVGQJQ-gdXaFlQUtGM",
      "auth": "if-YFywyb4g-bFB1hO9WMw=="
    };
    sendNewsletter(this.sub);
})
.catch(err => console.error("Could not subscribe to notifications", err));

export function sendNewsletter(sub) {
  console.log('init send')
  console.log(sub);
  const webpush = require('web-push');

  const vapidKeys = {
    "publicKey":"BML9Py6LHPBuJqFT0vKB4jk5NCv-Jfl1O__97PkVanHqJa5uzFD-TlUzgY-enxXQCirAbMVGQJQ-gdXaFlQUtGM",
    "privateKey":"SZ-C6z9rBf75PvOIhVeTwyr1vmKW-2xj8LFfS3EqW8Y"
  };
  
  webpush.setVapidDetails(
      'mailto:example@yourdomain.org',
      vapidKeys.publicKey,
      vapidKeys.privateKey
  );
  
  const allSubscriptions = [];
  allSubscriptions.push(sub);

  const notificationPayload = {
      "notification": {
          "title": "Angular News",
          "body": "Newsletter Available!",
          "icon": "assets/main-page-logo-small-hat.png",
          "vibrate": [100, 50, 100],
          "data": {
              "dateOfArrival": Date.now(),
              "primaryKey": 1
          },
          "actions": [{
              "action": "explore",
              "title": "Go to the site"
          }]
      }
  };

  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
  };
  Promise.all(
    allSubscriptions.map(sub => 
      webpush.sendNotification(sub, JSON.stringify(notificationPayload), {'headers': headers})
    )
  )
  .then(() => {
    //res.status(200).json({message: 'Newsletter sent successfully.'});
    console.log('Newsletter sent successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Error sending notification, reason: ", err);
    //res.sendStatus(500);
  });
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Comment: @JSONDerulo Hi, thanks for the answer. No because I have no way to access the Windows notification system cors policies, I think

Answer (score 0):

There are several Chrome extensions that can disable CORS locally. Here’s a link to one of them: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino